# Is any of Batman's technology extraterrestrial?

Tags: dc, batman

Since Bruce Wayne is rich, he get a lot of cool gadgets for his Batman costume.

Does he have anything Alien incorporated into his suit or weapons?  It seems that all he has is tech from Earth despite being in contact with powerful aliens.  The only thing Batman has that is Alien is the Kryptonite ring, is there anything else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's got a Bat-Alien-Repellent spray.

Comment: I think you mean "Alien Repellant Bat-Spray". ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the list of gadgets contained in [Batman's belt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman%27s_utility_belt) (wikipedia) there is nothing there that suggests alien technology. However, one of the primary functions of [Wayne Technologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Enterprises#Wayne_Technologies) is just that:

> Wayne Technologies, also known as WayneTech, is the biggest division of Wayne Enterprises. It is involved in the retrieval and research of alien technology.

From that we can assume that some of the gadgets Batman uses may contain reverse engineered tech from aliens. Some of the trophies Batman keeps in his cave may be of alien original, but he doesn't use them as part of his normal array of crime fighting tools.

There have also been instances where Batman has used an alien's technology against them; such as in [Superman/Batman Apocalypse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman/Batman%3a_Apocalypse) when he activites the Hell Spores to destroy Apokolips to save Kara.

In the Superman/Batman comics [Hiro Okamura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toyman#Hiro_Okamura) (Toyman) has an arrangement with Batman to supply him with additional technological gadgets.

Comment: If Batman were obviously using tech that could only be tracked back to WayneTech, it would be fairly obvious he was getting his tech from them (or stealing it from them, at least)

Comment: He augments a lot of Wayne Tech to fit his uses. He is also a brilliant innovator and inventer and creates his own equipment as well.

Comment: But I bet the stuff he augments (movies aside, and even they deal with the matter of 'where he gets those wonderful toys') is stuff that can be purchased off-the-shelf from WayneTech, which does not include their alien-inspired gizmos.

Comment: Just a thought, I read somewhere that he carried around some kryptonite in case Superman ever went bad. Not sure if that would be considered "technology" though, certainly a useful piece of rock though.

Comment: It's likely that, given the WayneTech/alien connection, the alien tech appears in less obvious ways.  Alien fibers strengthening his costume, alien compression tech to make the super-small smoke pellets, alien computing tech helping with sample analysis, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Batman does not use any obviously alien technologies.

Many of the technologies he does use, however, defy physics (his grapple, for one, is problematic - the rope is obscenely long, strong, yet fits into a tiny package).  Other items he uses are questionably plausible, but would impart other problems.

These problems could easily be tracked back to alien technology being incorporated into his gear, but also could be explained away as 'comic book physics', the same as Spidey's web shooters.

Comment: "the rope is obscenely long, strong, yet fits into a tiny package" - Spider silk? Carbon nanotube based material? Doesn't have to be alien at all.

Comment: Also, didn't they retcon Spiderman's web shooters to be organic built-ins sometime ago? (source: vague memory of cracked.com article).

Comment: @DVK: Yes to both, both have been mentioned (and were in my mind while writing).  [Batman's grapple gun is not feasable](http://dvice.com/archives/2008/07/believing-batma.php) and I can't find the reference, but I believe Spider Man would have to use about 25% of his body mass to webswing from one side of New York to the other (not to mention the pressure needed to fling webbing that far - if it were too light, it would blow off course, and the heavier it is, the more force it takes to propel it).

Comment: @DVK: In short, no it doesn't have to be alien (it fits normal comic physics) but alien tech can be used to help explain Batman's grapple gun.

Answer (score 1):

While working with the JL he's used alien tech from time to time... the link below is a panel of him using an alien weapon... a gun... from Apocalypse...yes this was a one timer and violated several of Batman's core beliefs but if you view the link, I think you'll see why he chose too do so.

[image]

I can't quote a book or panel number but I remember Supergirl giving/selling Batman Kryptonian fabric for the Batsuit-??

I would also consider the Sinestro and Green Lantern rings alien tech.